# Adobe Flash App -- Unique Device ID

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, device, udid

I'm developing an application using Adobe Flash (AS3) which runs mainly on tablets.
I would like users to pay. So they have to activate their application.
To do this I thought about providing an activation Code that is built using a univoque Device Identifier (UDID)
So, the customer provides me his UDID and I return the activation code which works only on his device.
My problem is (I searched everywhere)... how can I obtain an UDID using AS3?
Or also, do you suggest a different approch to reach my goal?

Thank you very much!

Daniele

Comment: You can't count on the device id being actually unique-  the user can regenerate it for privacy reasons at any time, and can set it to whatever they want if they use a custom ROM.

Comment: I hope you plan on doing that on google play only cos I'm pretty sure Apple will refuse your app on their store since you are simply violating their pricing policy. Won't be surprised if Google play will reject you as well. They do want %30 of your sale and your idea is to not give it to them, you'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct solution to what you are asking , It depends entirely on your needs and kind of app you are publishing.

> createUID() function in mx.utils package Generates a UID (unique
>   identifier) based on ActionScript's pseudo-random number generator and
>   the current time.
>
> But that may not help you as this ID is not machine dependent , user can simply publish his UID and your authentication key . User may need to install the app in other of his devices,  user may accidentally delete the file which will delete the originally generated UID too.

A 64-bit number (as a hex string) is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and remains constant for the lifetime of the user's device. **The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device**.This is accessible using java by constant **ANDROID_ID** there is no library in ActionScript-3 to access this . But you can use [this ane](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-DeviceId) to get it.

Or You can use a sign in from facebook [using this ane](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook) or google+ and use the customers unique id from there , but it would require him to give your app permissions to view some basic information.